# Docker volume plugin and start it

Tags: system-installation, docker

I have installed docker volume plugin and now need to start it.

https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-lvm-plugin

As per this document, you can start the plugin using the below command.

```
sudo systemctl start docker-lvm-plugin
```

I have Ubuntu 14.4 and does not have systemctl installed. So, how do I start it?

I see the this following folder.

```
pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ tree systemd/
systemd/
├── docker-lvm-plugin.service
└── docker-lvm-plugin.socket



pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin/systemd$ cat docker-lvm-plugin.service 
[Unit]
Description=Docker Volume Driver for lvm volumes
Documentation=man:docker-lvm-plugin(8)
Before=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/docker/docker-lvm-plugin
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-lvm-plugin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl` is part of the new SystemD init system present in Ubuntu 16.04 and newer.

Old versions of Ubuntu (so before 16.04) use `upstart` instead, which uses the `service` command.

In order to start the service, use this command instead:

```
sudo service docker-lvm-plugin start
```

Note that if the installer itself installed the service files in a systemd-only directory, it will not work with your system. You either need to get an older (or alternate) version of the package built for `upstart`-based systems or you need to [update to 16.04 or newer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu).

Comment: thanks..I get this error now...pr@pr-ubuntu:~/ba/docker-lvm-plugin$ sudo service docker-lvm-plugin start
docker-lvm-plugin: unrecognized service

Comment: Edited my post. You'll either need to install an upstart-aware version of the package, or you'll need to update to 16.04.

Comment: thank you..How can I install a upstart-aware version of the package? i Have given the contents of the systemd service file for the reference.

Comment: @user1050619 I am not aware of any upstart-compatible versions of the Docker LVM plugin. You can write your own startup script if you feel so inclined (out of scope of this question), though I'd suggest upgrading if you can.

Answer (score 2):

Do `sudo apt-get install systemd` to get the "systemctl" command, then do `sudo systemctl start docker` Then do `sudo systemctl start docker-lvm-plugin`