# How to encrypt a volume for docker container

Tags: encryption, docker

How do I encrypt a volume for Docker container? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried https://github.com/projectatomic/docker-lvm-plugin . However it says

```
make: *** No rule to make target `main.go', needed by `lvm-plugin-build'.  Stop.
```

I also tried https://medium.com/@kalahari/docker-data-volume-snapshots-and-encryption-with-lvm-and-luks-ce80e0555225. It is not able to find specified github location.

Can someone point me to the right documentation to do this. I need to encrypt the volume which will be used for keeping data at rest secure.

Comment: This question is showing up in the Low Quality Post queue, likely due to it's length. Would you be so kind as to expand it a bit perhaps by telling us what you've tried, the [documentation you've reviewed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), etc.. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932992/docker-volume-plugin-and-start-it

Comment: I know this is necromancing by about a year but this is still really annoying, the Docker documentation says that it is possible: ["Volume drivers let you store volumes on remote hosts or cloud providers, to encrypt the contents of volumes, or to add other functionality."](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). But nothing out there that I can find really expounds on this.